# Shell script for Multiple Linux Servers Health report in html with column color change based on condition

Tags: html, linux, bash, csv, health-check

This code will fetch the data from Multiple servers and store in CSV file.
I am trying to get same data into HTML table format with the condition base columns, like if disk free space is less in 20% then columns of that server becomes yellow if less then 10% then becomes red.

```
rm -f /tmp/health*
touch /tmp/health.csv
#Servers File Path 
FILE="/tmp/health.csv"
USR=root
#Create CSV File Haeader
echo "  Date, Hostname, Connectivity, Root-FreeSpace, Uptime, OS-version, Total-ProcesCount, VmToolsversion, ServerLoad, Memory, Disk, CPU, LastReboot-Time, UserFailedLoginCount, " > $FILE
for server in `more /root/servers.txt`
do
_CMD="ssh $USR@$server"

Date=$($_CMD date)
Connectivity=$($_CMD ping -c 1 google.com &> /dev/null && echo connected || echo disconnected)
ip_add=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print$2'} | cut -f2 -d:`
RootFreeSpace=$($_CMD df / | tail -n +2 |awk '{print $5}')
Uptime=$($_CMD uptime | sed 's/.*up \([^,]*\), .*/\1/')
OSVersion=$($_CMD cat /etc/redhat-release)
TotalProcess=$($_CMD ps axue | grep -vE "^USER|grep|ps" | wc -l)
VmtoolStatus=$($_CMC vmtoolsd -v |awk '{print $5}')
ServerLoad=$($_CMD uptime |awk -F'average:' '{ print $2}'|sed s/,//g | awk '{ print $2}')
Memory=$($_CMD free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }')
Disk=$($_CMD df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%s\t\t", $5}')
CPU=$($_CMD top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}')
Lastreboottime=$($_CMD who -b | awk '{print $3,$4}')
FailedUserloginCount=$($_CMD cat /var/log/secure |grep "Failed" | wc -l)
#updated data in CSV 
echo "$Date,$HostName,$Connectivity,$RootFreeSpace,$Uptime,$OSVersion,$TotalProcess,$VmtoolStatus,$ServerLoad,$Memory,$Disk,$CPU,$Lastreboottime,$FailedUserloginCount" >> $FILE
done
```

Comment: this Q is too complex. You should edit it to solve the problem for one column, then you can apply the solution to your other columns. And it seems that you'll need to figure-out/understand how to make a simple html document. (Wouldn't the colors be applied as html attributes (may not be the exact right term)). Good luck.

Comment: I am able to create HTML but just want to add multiple condition in If statement like 

```print "<tr>"                                   
for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {                   
  printf "%s", "<td"                           
  if ($i+0>80) printf " bgcolor=#FF3333"       
  else if ($i+0>60) printf " bgcolor=#FFCC33"  
  else printf " bgcolor=#99FF33"               
  print ">" $i "</td>"                         
}                                              
print "</tr>"

Comment: if you've already got everything working to populate the CSV file then the code you've posted has nothing to do with the title (generating color columns in HTML); I'd suggest you close/delete this question and create a new question that focuses on your html issues; in particular ... provide an example of the CSV file, provide an example of the desired HTML (to match the sample CSV data), and provide the code you've tried so far re: generating HTML

Comment: Also, I don't know your exact situation and constraints (and how much time you can spend on this), but you should be able to send most/all of those remote commands as one "payload" via ssh, and save the output to a local file. Then it will be simpler to write an awk script that processes each output file(s) into the HTML you need. In the future, when you have code, include it in the body of your Q, rather than in comments. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse selected text to get formatting like `code/data/reqdOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. But +1 for having code in your first S.O.Q!Good luck.